# copy worksheet excel VBA fine tuning. Copy from certain cells, paste in certain cells & worksheet naming,

Tags: vba, excel

**EDIT:** I updated some code and I am getting an now error message now as well. Error is shown below.

I found a piece of code on this site and copies a worksheet to another workbook like I want, however I want to do some fine tuning. I need the source worksheet to copy all the information in the cells from cell "A11" - "J11" until the information in the rows end.

The copied information needs to be posted in cells "A4" - "J4" and down the rows until there is no more information to paste.

When the worksheet is copied it needs to be named a certain name (let's say it needs to be named "Customer Information") however, there will be a current sheet in the destination workbook by the same name. Is there a way to copy it over without adding (1) to the end of the name since there is already a tab with that name.

Here is the code I currently have

```
Sub UpdateCustomerInformation()

Dim wkbSource As Workbook
Dim wkbDest As Workbook
Dim shttocopy As Worksheet
Dim wbname As String
Dim destSheet As Worksheet



' check if the file is open
Ret = Isworkbookopen("\\showdog\service\\Service_job_PO\Customer Information - Query.xls")
If Ret = False Then
' open file
Set wkbSource = Workbooks.Open("\\showdog\service\\Service_job_PO\Customer Information - Query.xls")
Else
'Just make it active
 'Workbooks("C:\stack\file1.xlsx").Activate
 Set wkbSource = Workbooks("Customer Information - Query.xls")
 End If

' check if the file is open

Ret = Isworkbookopen("\\showdog\service\Service Jobs.xlsm")
If Ret = False Then
' open file
Set wkbDest = Workbooks.Open("\\showdog\service\Service Jobs.xlsm")
Set destSheet = wkbDest.Sheets("Customer Information")
'perform copy
Set shttocopy = wkbSource.Sheets("Report")
shttocopy.Range("A11:J11").End(xlDown).Copy
```

Error gets thrown here: "object doesn't support this property or method"

```
wkbDest.Sheets(destSheet.Name).Range("A4:J4").End(xlDown).Paste
```

I am unsure why though. I thought I had everything correct, but I obviously don't

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

wkbDest.Save
wkbDest.Close

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

'close file
Else
'Just make it active
 'Workbooks("C:\stack\file2.xlsx").Activate
 Set wkbDest = Workbooks("Service Jobs.xlsm")
 Set destSheet = wkbDest.Sheets("Customer Information")
'perform copy
Set shttocopy = wkbSource.Sheets("Report")
shttocopy.Range("A11:J11").End(xlDown).Copy
wkbDest.Sheets(destSheet.Name).Range("A4:J4").End(xlDown).Paste

End If



End Sub

Function Isworkbookopen(filename As String)
Dim ff As Long, ErrNo As Long
Dim wkb As Workbook
Dim nam As String

wbname = filename
On Error Resume Next

ff = FreeFile()
Open filename For Input Lock Read As #ff
Close ff
ErrNo = Err
On Error GoTo 0
Select Case ErrNo
Case 0: Isworkbookopen = False
Case 70: Isworkbookopen = True
Case Else: Error ErrNo
End Select
End Function
```

I am unsure how to accomplish the tasks mentioned above. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you want to manipulate the data (or properties like name) of the destination sheet you'll need another worksheet object for that (Dim destSheet As Worksheet). Then instead of doing a "shttocopy.Copy" you'll need to break it out and be more specific (shttocopy.Range("A11:J11").Copy) and paste it more specifically to destSheet ( wkbDest.Sheets(destSheet.name).Range("A4:J4").Paste ). There's a lot of hard-defined elements of that code you pasted, so if you want it to be more robust, I might recommend changing some of that. If you need more help I can provide a more complicated answer.

Comment: I'll give that a shot. I have an idea of how to accomplish my task with that information. I just wasn't sure how to get it started. I'll let you know how I progress. Thanks!

Comment: I followed your advice, however I am now getting an error. I updated the code so you can see what I did.

Comment: @RichardHorvath, there is only `PasteSpecial` method for the `Range` object. You can edit the line to look like this : `wkbDest.destSheet.Range("A4:J4").End(xlDown).PasteSpecial` - notice i changed the *sheet part* also, you already set the sheet, you dont need to do it again.

Comment: See [Range.PasteSpecial Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839476%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

Comment: I did that, however I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Try this (delete the wkbDest) `destSheet.Range("A4:J4").End(xlDown).PasteSpecial`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74868/discussion-between-richard-horvath-and-branislav-kollar).

Answer (score 0):

This code can be changed.

```
shttocopy.Range("A11:J11").End(xlDown).Copy
wkbDest.Sheets(destSheet.Name).Range("A4:J4").End(xlDown).Paste
```

to

```
shttocopy.Range("A11:J11").Copy destsheet.range("A4")
```

You do not need to put destSheet.name inside of Sheets()
While the macro recorder will create separate copy/paste instructions, it should be rewritten like above.

End(xlDown) is typically used to locate the next available row for copying and should not be used this way.

If you want to copy one row at a time use End(xlUP) to find the next available row:

```
lRow = DestSheet.Range("A65536").end(xlUP).row + 1
shttocopy.Range("A1").Copy destsheet.range("A" & lrow)
```

If you need to identify the bottom right address of the range you are copying from use the following:

```
 dim aRange as range

 set aRange = shttocopy.range(Range("A1").address, Cells(shttocopy.usedrange.rows.count, shttocopy.usedrange.columns.count).address)

  Shttocopy.arange.copy ...
```

The Copy on one line and paste method on another often throws errors and it is advisable to replace it. as suggested above.

Comment: No errors or anything are thrown for this, however it shows that nothing is done. it's just a blank sheet and nothing is copied over

Answer (score 0):

To copy the whole range form `shttocopy` (using what @Rgo said and presuming there are no blank cells inside the range in `shttocopy`) to the bottom of the existing range in `destsheet` + 1 row (again presuming no blanks in column "A").

```
With shttocopy
    .Range(.Range("A11"), .Range("A11").End(xlDown).End(xlToRight)).Copy _
    destsheet.Range("A4").End(xlDown).Offset(1)
End With
```

Comment: When using this i still get an error that says "application defined or object defined error".

Comment: I am not familiar with embedding the .End(xlDown).End(xlroRight) inside the Range...Copy. I would suggest if you are trying to identify the down right edge of the cell address to do so outside the copy command like I wrote above. You can also used the source worksheet .UsedRange.columns.count to get the last column number and the .UsedRange.Rows.Count to get the last row. These two embedding inside the Cells(row,column) will return the address. Lastly, when using the Range function inside another range, try adding .address.

Comment: @rgo Well the `End` method returns a *Range*, so you can again manipulate it as a *Range*, for example using another `End` method and this again returns a *Range* object, so you can for example copy it, or select it, or other range methods it.